# How to bind data grid in ViewCell

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid

I am Implementing data grid with infinite scrolling, for that I am adding my datagrid to the Listview ViewCell.My xaml is like

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <extended:InfiniteScrollBehavior IsLoadingMore="{Binding IsBusy}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <datagrid:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="5" RowHeight="30" HeaderHeight="30" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#5b9bd5" HeaderTextColor="White">
                            <datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Job#" PropertyName="Job" Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Source" PropertyName="Source" Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Location" PropertyName="Location"  Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Service" PropertyName="Service"  Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Assignee" PropertyName="Assignee"  Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Service Date" PropertyName="ServiceDate" Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Time Slot" PropertyName="TimeSlot" Width="0.5*"/>
                                <datagrid:DataGridColumn Title="Service Status" PropertyName="ServiceStatus" Width="0.5*"/>
                            </datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <datagrid:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                                <datagrid:PaletteCollection>
                                    <Color>#d2deef</Color>
                                    <Color>#eaeff7</Color>
                                </datagrid:PaletteCollection>
                            </datagrid:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                        </datagrid:DataGrid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Grid Padding="6" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>
                    <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="DeepPink" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
```

and my ViewModel is Like

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isBusy;
    private const int PageSize = 25;
    public InfiniteScrollCollection<Jobs> Items { get; }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
        }
    }


    #region fields
    private List<Jobs> jobs;
    private Jobs selectedItem;
    private bool isRefreshing;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<Jobs> Jobs
    {
        get { return jobs; }
        set { jobs = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(jobs)); }
    }

    public Jobs SelectedJob
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Job Selected : " + value?.Job);
        }
    }

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get { return isRefreshing; }
        set { isRefreshing = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing)); }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Jobs = new List<Jobs>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Jobs.Add(new Jobs { Job = i, Source = "Source" + i, Location = "Loaction" + i, Service = "Service" + i, Assignee = "Assignee" + i, ServiceDate = "ServiceDate" + i, TimeSlot = "TimeSlot" + i, ServiceStatus = "ServiceStatus" + i });
        }

        Items = new InfiniteScrollCollection<Jobs>
        {
            OnLoadMore = async () =>
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                // load the next page
                var page = Items.Count / PageSize;

                var items = await GetItemsAsync(page, PageSize);

                IsBusy = false;

                // return the items that need to be added
                return items;
            },
            OnCanLoadMore = () =>
            {
                return Items.Count < Jobs.Count;
            }
        };

        DownloadDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        var items = await GetItemsAsync(pageIndex: 0, pageSize: PageSize);

        Items.AddRange(items);
    }
    public async Task<List<Jobs>> GetItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        return Jobs.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }

    private async void CmdRefresh()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        // wait 3 secs for demo
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Every time my cell is showing 25 items in cell.Can anyone please help me how to load data in only one cell and every time add the extra data below of previous data.

Answer (score 0):

give your ListView a name and change the

```
<datagrid:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference Name=<NameOfListView>}}"
```

Comment: hi @Neil same problem again

Comment: My binding expression might be wrong. Will look and get back to you

Comment: hi @Neil any help for this??

Comment: I am sorry, haven't had a chance to check on this. In the meantime, can you look on the output tab when the page is displayed. Are there any binding errors? this will help narrow down the problem.